# How to send a table with SQL information through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to display a table onto a html page that contains users SQL data.

Assume I can connect and there is information in the table.

```
<?php
echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Hair Color</th>
        </tr>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['first']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['last']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['color']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">";
  ?>
```

Where am I going wrong because no data is being output?

Comment: Do you have any data in your database?

Comment: Check your query is executing ?

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_query(), but if you are you need a database link.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: As shown in an answer below, this line `echo "<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">";` should be either `echo '<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">';` or escaping your double quotes like this `echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"updateTable\" id=\"btn\">";` other than that, your code is fine and check to see if you do have data in your DB and that your columns are correctly named. Plus *"assuming"* you are connected to your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do consider switching over to `MySQLi_` and/or PDO and prepared statements. `MySQL_` is deprecated.

Do read these two articles (*before going LIVE*):

- [**How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724)
- [**Owasp.org**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)

There was one line with a syntax error, this one:

```
echo "<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">";
```

Which should either be written as:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">';
```

or:

```
echo "<input type='button' value='updateTable' id='btn'>";
```

or escaping the double quotes:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"updateTable\" id=\"btn\">";
```

### Tested on my own server:

```
<?php
echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Hair Color</th>
</tr>";

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$mydb = "your_db";
$table = "your_table";
mysql_select_db($mydb) or die ('Unable to select database');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['first']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['last']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['color']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"updateTable\" id=\"btn\">";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

Below line is causing the error,

```
 echo "<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">";
```

should be something like this

```
 echo '<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">';
```

PHP code:

```
  <?php     

        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Hair Color</th>
            </tr>";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['first']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['last']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['color']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        echo '<input type="button" value="updateTable" id="btn">';          

?>
```

Comment: Better yet would be to turn off the interpreter when outputting the hardcoded HTML.  That way it still works without escaping if/when a `'` has to be embedded somewhere, and you get syntax highlighting on the HTML.